# How do I align particles to the center of the object?

Tags: particles, physics

I’ll keep it short,

I found myself playing with particles on Blender and I am unable to align them with the center of the object that emits them (which happens to be a cube).

This is what I get (default setup particles, I did not change anything):
[image]

And this is what I am trying to achieve:
[image]

So, any idea on what type of configuration I should be using? Thx for your time and happy blender!

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer to my own question... lol

So here it is, it can be of help to any of you, or so I hope.

In short, you have to rotate the object (particles) in the X-axis -90º so it looks as it’s shown in the following image.
[image]

Then you just go Control+A, Apply Rotation and then you have it!
[image]